# What are the advantages to using tmux?

Tags: tmux, gnu-screen

What are the advantages to using `tmux` or `screen`? Can you provide some simple examples that will instantly improve my workflow? (I use SSH). Also, I'd be happy to mark this question as "community wiki" but I'm not sure how.

Comment: There is a thread on Unix & Linux on this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/549/tmux-vs-gnu-screen

Comment: Thanks Jason - clear now this isn't the right place for the question.

Comment: Might as well throw in a couple thoughts since people seems to like this question. 1) you can get disconnected from SSH and just "reattach" to anything you were working on 2) with tmux you can have many "terminals" open on a single screen, these are called "panes"